# Accessing Makefile variables in code?

Tags: c++, makefile, arduino, gnu-make

**UPDATED PROGRESS**

I am sorry I forgot to specify this question as an Arduino question. I just assumed that it's a preprocessor problem which is kind of independent of what platform this is being executed on.

I am using Arduino-Make and I am trying to pass in USERNAME and PASSWORD

```
BOARD_TAG    = mega2560
CPPFLAGS     = -DUSERNAME="$(USERNAME)" -DPASSWORD="$(PASSWORD)"
include $(ARDMK_DIR)/Arduino.mk
```

Command line:

`make USERNAME="HELLO" PASSWORD="WORLD"`

Code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  String auth_raw2(USERNAME : PASSWORD);
  Serial.println(auth_raw2);
}


void loop() {}
```

I am getting this error:

```
macro.ino:10:29: error: found ‘:’ in nested-name-specifier, expected ‘::’
macro.ino:10:20: error: ‘HELLO’ has not been declared
```

Comment: You also probably want `"` around your defines to make them string literals, but you still can't `+` them like that.

Comment: [`String`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject) is a class provided by the Arduino C++ standard library (and it does have a `+` operator).

Comment: Got a semiworking solution, but found another problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966878/stringification-working-with-usernamepassword-but-not-for-serialtoken

Answer (score 1):

What you want is

```
String auth_raw( USERNAME ":" PASSWORD );
```

That will do the proper literal string concatenation you're looking for. The compiler will run adjacent string literals together into a single string. So if you have

```
char a[] = "The " "quick" " brown " "fox";
```

it treats it the same as if you wrote

```
char a[] = "The quick brown fox";
```

I'm not sure about putting " around the values provided on the command line to make.

Comment: I have the following: `CPPFLAGS = -DUSERNAME="$(USERNAME)" -DPASSWORD="$(PASSWORD)"` with `String auth_raw2(USERNAME : PASSWORD);` My make: `make USERNAME="HELLO" PASSWORD="WORLD"` and I am getting `macro.ino:10:29: error: found ‘:’ in nested-name-specifier, expected ‘::’` and `macro.ino:10:20: error: ‘HELLO’ has not been declared`

Comment: The : has to be in quotes between USERNAME and PASSWORD. Otherwise it's not a string, and won't enable the string concatenation.

Comment: Also, the quoting can be very messy as you pass the text in from the command line, through make, and on into the compiler. I suggest printing the values via printf, and trying different combinations of quotes in different places until you find what works.

Comment: Your comment sort of worked. I ran into another problem though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966878/stringification-working-with-usernamepassword-but-not-for-serialtoken

Answer (score 1):

According to [the literature at Arduino's Site](http://arduino.cc):

Concatenating in a constructor ["gives unpredictable results because 'auth_raw' never got an initial value before you started concatenating different data types.
For best results, initialize your Strings before you concatenate them."](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringAdditionOperator)

---

As far as the variables you are passing to your makefile are concerned, the syntax is correct, and the commandline -D to define those variables is as well valid. However, as the documentation points out, you should avoid mixing integers and strings when passing to a constructor, though it would be perfectly valid to construct the String first, and then concatenate the values.

Comment: Updated to use only strings.