# Stringification working with USERNAME:PASSWORD but not for SERIAL:TOKEN?

Tags: c++, makefile, arduino, c-preprocessor

I have the following Makefile (If you are asking me why there's \" included you can refer to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963654/accessing-makefile-variables-in-code))

```
BOARD_TAG    = mega2560
CPPFLAGS     = -DUSERNAME=\"$(USERNAME)\" -DPASSWORD=\"$(PASSWORD)\"
include $(ARDMK_DIR)/Arduino.mk
```

and code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  String auth_raw2(USERNAME ":" PASSWORD);
  Serial.println(auth_raw2);
}
void loop() {}
```

when I compile this with `make USERNAME=hello PASSWORD=world`, everything works and I see 'hello:world' being printed out.

However, if I substitute USERNAME to SERIAL and PASSWORD to TOKEN:

```
BOARD_TAG    = mega2560
CPPFLAGS     = -DSERIAL=\"$(SERIAL)\" -DTOKEN=\"$(TOKEN)\"
include $(ARDMK_DIR)/Arduino.mk
```

and

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  String auth_raw2(SERIAL ":" TOKEN);
  Serial.println(auth_raw2);
}
void loop() {}
```

I am getting the error, `macro.ino:5:27: error: expected ‘)’ before string constant`

Note that $USERNAME is defined on my linux box as `disappearedng` while $PASSWORD, $SERIAL, and $TOKEN are undefined.

**WHY does this work for USERNAME:PASSWORD but not for SERIAL:TOKEN?**

Comment: I don't believe this question is specifically for arduino so I included C and C++ as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems like Arduino overrides the $SERIAL parameter.

Switching SERIAL to DSERIAL makes compiling ok